# Add two more items to animated slider

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am using a CSS3 text slider that was made for 3 lines of text.  I wish to add two more lines but cannot figure out how to recalculate keyframes.

I added the additional items in CSS, but do not know how to recalculate the keyframes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<p class="item-1">Text Line 1</p>    
<p class="item-2">Text Line 2</p>
<p class="item-3">Text Line 3</p>  
<p class="item-4">Text Line 4</p>
<p class="item-5">Text Line 5</p>
```

CSS:

```
.item-1, 
.item-2, 
.item-3,
.item-4,
.item-5 {
    font-family: 'Suez One';
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 80px;
    color: white !important;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    text-shadow: 8px 8px 3px #000000;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
    z-index: 1001;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
            animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1{
    -webkit-animation-name: anim-1;
            animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2{
    -webkit-animation-name: anim-2;
            animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3{
    -webkit-animation-name: anim-3;
            animation-name: anim-3;
}
.item-4{
    -webkit-animation-name: anim-4;
            animation-name: anim-4;
}
.item-5{
    -webkit-animation-name: anim-5;
            animation-name: anim-5;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-1 {
    0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    8.3%, 25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
    0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-2 {
    0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    41.63%, 58.29% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
    0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    41.63%, 58.29% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-3 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes anim-3 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-4 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-4 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-5 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes anim-5 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

When posting this question I got an error message "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add more details"  That's why I am typing this.  Trying to have some more words so it will let me post this question.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: you can probably try more easier way, here is an idea with one keyframe : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53796736/8620333

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I really want to make this work.  I hate the idea of starting over from scratch.   It's a great learning experience as well.   I would really like to understand the theory, so that, for example, I could, if I wanted, add even more lines of text.

Comment: The code you're trying to reuse has a big architectural flaw: if you want to add/remove slides you need to rewrite all the animations, as they occupy a different percentage of the overall loop timeline. The only way to make it flexible would be to write the required CSS at page load based on current number of slides, using JavaScript. But that kind of defeats the purpose: writing a JavaScript slider is simpler than writing a CSS one on the fly, using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that writes the animation on the fly, based on number of slides:

```js
'use strict';

var slider = document.querySelector('.css-slider'),
    slides = slider.querySelectorAll('p'),
    css = '';

for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  css += '.css-slider>*:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + '){animation-name:a-' + i + '}' + ('@keyframes a-' + i + '{') + ('0%,' + i * 100 / slides.length + '%{transform: translatex(-100%)}') + (i * 100 / slides.length + 25 / slides.length + '%,' + ((i + 1) * 100 / slides.length - 25 / slides.length) + '%{transform: translatex(0)}') + ((i + 1) * 100 / slides.length + '%,100%{transform: translatex(100%)}') + '}';
}
css += '.css-slider>*{animation-duration:' + slides.length * 4 + 's;';

var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet) {
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Suez+One');
.css-slider > * {
    font-family: 'Suez One';
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 55px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.css-slider, .css-slider > *:last-child {
  position: relative;
}
.css-slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slider">
  <p>Text Line 1</p>    
  <p>Text Line 2</p>
  <p>Text Line 3</p>  
  <p>Text Line 4</p>
  <p>Text Line 5</p>
  <p>Text Line 6</p>
  <p>Text Line 7</p>
</div>
```

Note I changed your initial markup, as I wanted it to write a more general solution, not one tailored to your particular case.
But if you're only interested in the CSS for 5 items and you want to keep your markup here's what you're asking for:

```css
.item-1 { -webkit-animation-name: a-0; animation-name: a-0 }
.item-2 { -webkit-animation-name: a-1; animation-name: a-1 }
.item-3 { -webkit-animation-name: a-2; animation-name: a-2 }
.item-4 { -webkit-animation-name: a-3; animation-name: a-3 }
.item-5 { -webkit-animation-name: a-4; animation-name: a-4 }

@-webkit-keyframes a-0 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%) }
  5%, 15% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  20%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@keyframes a-0 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%) }
  5%, 15% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  20%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@-webkit-keyframes a-1 {
  0%, 20% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%)}
  25%, 35% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@keyframes a-1 {
  0%, 20% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%)}
  25%, 35% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@-webkit-keyframes a-2 {
  0%, 40% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%) }
  45%, 55% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  60%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@keyframes a-2 {
  0%, 40% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%) }
  45%, 55% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  60%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@-webkit-keyframes a-3 {
  0%, 60% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%) }
  65%, 75% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@keyframes a-3 {
  0%, 60% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%) }
  65%, 75% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@-webkit-keyframes a-4 {
  0%, 80% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%) }
  85%, 95% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}

@keyframes a-4 {
  0%, 80% { -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%); transform: translatex(-100%) }
  85%, 95% { -webkit-transform: translatex(0); transform: translatex(0) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translatex(100%); transform: translatex(100%) }
}
```

And the principle behind the keyframes is:

```
.item-${n+1} { animation-name: a-${n} }

@keyframes a-${n} {
  0%, enterStart { left state ruleset }
  enterEnd, leaveStart { center state ruleset }
  leaveEnd, 100% { right state ruleset }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on the first line.  Does this need to be wrapped in a document ready statement?   I assume it needs to be wrapped in a <script> tag....correct?

Comment: It will error if it's run before `.css-slider` is added to DOM.

Comment: And yes, JavaScript needs to be wrapped inside `<script type="application/javascript">/* code here */</script>` or to be saved in a `.js` file and loaded with `<script src="/path/to/file"></script>`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, but you are speaking in technical way and this is not my area of expertise.  I understand HTML and CSS all day long, but I am new to scripting.  The script you provided needs to be in the header wrapped in a <script> tag?   Or loaded from a separate file?   Is the script complete or does it need a document ready statement?

I tried this and the text was all on the screen at the same time....telling me the script wasn't working.

Comment: Scripts are complete without a `document.ready` wrapper. When you choose to run it is your own choice, not the authors'. IMHO, the best way to load it would be to place it in a `.js` file and reference it using a `<script ref="path/to/file"></script>` **at the end of the page**. Somewhere before `</body>` ending tag. What error are you getting? Did you look at the markup I used? I didn't use your markup because I don't agree with it. There's no point in adding 1 class for each item.

Comment: @Daniel, I updated the CSS for 5 items in my answer to work with your current markup. Should be as easy as copy/paste-ing. You can also revert it to animating `left` property instead of `transform`, but I strongly advise against it.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation.   I often just use Notepad++ for HTML and CSS but the code you provided wasn't working so I loaded it into Dreamweaver and it said there was a syntax error on Line 1.  I have tried it in the main HTML wrapped in a <script> tag (at the bottom) and also tried loading it from an external file.

Comment: You must have gone back and edited the code snippet....because it originally started with the line:  "let slider = document.querySelector(".css-slider"),"  and now it starts with "'use strict';"

I will toy around with it and comment back if I can get it going.....

Comment: *A sytax error* doesn't say much. ***What** syntax error* would allow me to understand what the error was (could have been running the script too early, or not matching your markup, or having a different encoding than your system, or having different line breaks... it could be a lot of things, really - it also depends on what OS and what browser you use). Or it could be a different error altogether. As you can [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/Lxep6nzh/), the script works. Change number of items and it will write the CSS. Inspect the source and copy/paste it. Can't really help more.

Comment: @Daniel, yes, ***I did change the script***. The one in the answer is more general - parsed through Babel to be es2015 compatible - hence working in IE, while the one in the fiddle is what I actually wrote and is es2017, only working in modern browsers.

Comment: The edited code works perfectly!   That's fantastic.  I will mark your answer as the accepted answer.  I just need to slow it down and it will be perfect.

Comment: @Daniel, the `animation-duration` is set by the script, giving each slide `4s` (on line 10, around `+ slides.length * 4 + 's;';`). You can remove that line and simply set the overall loop duration to how many seconds you want. Or you could increase the slide duration, changing `4` to `7` or any other number of secs. If changing it doesn't seem to have any effect, you are probably setting it elsewhere in your current CSS, using a stronger selector. It's `20s` in the code you posted.

Comment: Changed the 4 to 6 and all is perfect.  Thank you again!

Comment: One other quick question.  If I wanted the text to slide in from a different direction (from the right....or even from the top or bottom....how would that be accomplished?   Also, can the text exit the same way it entered?  Say, slide in from right, then slight back out to the right?

Comment: @Daniel, CSS based sliders are one giant loop which is tuned to mimic a slider. But from a production-level point of view, they're a joke. I'd call them childish. You can't stop or reverse them and each time you want to change something you need to rewrite the whole bloody thing. While JavaScript sliders, such as Slick, Owl or Swiper, are completely free, tested cross-browser/cross-device and providing enterprise level quality. Having any of them as option, it makes absolutely no sense trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Making your own slider is pretty much like making your own car. You'll feel cool, you'll learn a lot, but you can't compare it with a factory car. And I'm not talking about comparison with a Bugatti or a Lambo. You can't even compare it with a budget car.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am not opposed to a JS solution, just trouble finding one that will do the slight zooming.  I will check out the ones you mentioned.

Comment: You're unlikely to find a stock car with pink tires, but that's hardly a reason to start making one from scratch. The slight zoom-in hover effect can be found on SO and can be easily added to ***any*** image. Therefore it can be added to images used inside a slider. It's unlikely that any slider has it as an option.

Comment: I don't want it to zoom on hover.....I just want every image to fade in as it slowly zooms.   Just to give a static picture some motion.   This is for the background of the site and not intended to have any effect from anything the user does.


What I actually want is have the first picture to zoom in, the second picture to zoom out.....alternating every-other picture.....