# How can I increase this css animation for 4 items?

Tags: css, animation

My Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/kennyv91/pen/YzwLpar), but I cannot get the same animation for more than 4 items. Can someone help break down the animations for me? Referring to mozilla docs was not super helpful.

```
.dynamic-words span {
    animation: wordsScroll 4.5s ease-in infinite;
}
```

Comment: 4 el., each 1.5 s delay, 4*1,5 = 6 s total + work on keyframes %.

Comment: Yes, increasing the delay to 6s allows me to get 4 items, but the animation is not as smooth as it overlaps each other. Is there a direct translation for keyframes instead of just trying percentages until it works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796213/css-text-animation-replace-text/53796417#53796417 You can apply something similar.

Comment: I have it working. Thank you